# Accessing JS variable in Razor and Aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my code:

```
<% if (someCondition) { %>

    var activeTab = $("#myTabs").tabs("option", "active");
    var language = <% myLanguages[activeTab] %> ;

<% } %>
```

myLanguages is of type Dictionary.

I want to access myLanguages[activeTab]. How do I do this?

Comment: This doesn't look like Razor syntax...

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. `myLanguages` exists on the server. `activeTab` exists in the client. You can't use a client variable as an indexer into a server variable. At least not in any manner remotely like what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this variable gets the value of the variable, at render time :

```
<% if (someCondition) { %>

    var activeTab = $("#kioskTabs").tabs("option", "active");
    var language = '@Html.Raw(myLanguages[activeKioskTab])';

<% } %>
```

Comment: It throws an error that activeTab isn't recognized.

Comment: @petko_stankoski : Please view source of your page, you should see the language variable, setted correctly, maybe error comes from another part of your script. By the way i updated my answer, added quotes.

Comment: yes, wrapping in single quote worked for me once too.